# Function isn't called with responsed data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I got a weird problem... I lost almost 2 hrs and I have no idea why it doesn't work.

It should sum all values for every dept where username = name choosed by select and where date = date choosed by datepicker.

It works great on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/defuseer/mrp3qxgq/74/) but when I am trying use it with responsed data it doesn't work and don't have any errors in console.

What am I doing wrong? This is code in my app not the same which is in jsFiddle

HTML:

```
<div layout="row">
  <md-datepicker ng-model="myDateUser" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
           {{myDateUser}}
           <md-input-container flex="50">
               <label for="repeatSelect"> Select user: </label>
               <md-select ng-model="data.model" ng-change="sum(data.model)">
                     <md-option ng-value="logins.name" ng-repeat="logins in chooseLogins">{{logins.name}}</md-option>
               </md-select>
           </md-input-container>
           <br/>
           <hr/>
           <tt>{{data.model}}</tt>
         </div>
  <md-table-container>
    <table md-table>
      <thead md-head>
        <tr md-row>
          <th md-column>Dept</th>
          <th md-column>Total time</th>
          <th md-column></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody md-body>
        <tr ng-if="!data.model" md-row md-select="test" md-on-select="" md-auto-select ng-repeat="test in tests">
          <td md-cell>{{ test.dept }}</td>
          <td md-cell>{{ test.total }}</td>
          <td md-cell></td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-if="data.model" md-row md-select="test" md-on-select="" md-auto-select ng-repeat="(key,val) in data.model">
          <td md-cell>{{ key }}</td>
          <td md-cell>{{ val }}</td>
          <td md-cell></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </md-table-container>
```

JS:

```
function getTotalTime() {
      $http.get('db_files/totalTimeDB.php').then(function(response) {
      $scope.data = response.data;
              $scope.sum = function(name) {

                        let model = $scope.data.filter(function(item) {
                            return (item.username == name && TheDate(item))
                        });

                        let tests = {};
                        model.forEach(function(item) {
                            if (!tests.hasOwnProperty(item.dept)) {
                                tests[item.dept] = 0;
                            }
                            tests[item.dept] += parseFloat(item.task_time);
                        });
                        $scope.data.model = tests;
                    }
                    function TheDate(item){
                      if($scope.myDateUser){
                        var myDateUser = new Date($scope.myDateUser);
                        var itemDate = new Date(item.task_end);
                        console.log("task_end " + item.task_end);
                        console.log("myDate " + $scope.myDateUser);

                        if(myDateUser.getFullYear() != itemDate.getFullYear() || myDateUser.getMonth() != itemDate.getMonth()){
                          return false;
                        }
                      }
                        return true
                    }
```

Example console.log from `$scope.data = response.data;`

```
Object
dept:"Test2"
status:"Closed"
task:"test test test"
task_end:"2016-09-02"
task_start:"2016-09-02"
task_time:"80"
username:"Nelson"
__proto__:Object
```

It works like show total sum only where username = choosed name and TheDate function is ignored. Also console.log shows nothing ( in example jsFiddle console.log shows selected date and name )
It looks like the function isn't called.

Comment: Your code doesn't correspond to logs. No code prints _"task_start"_, _"myDate"_ must be printed, but not. Please, mend your post.

Comment: Where are you getting `response.data` ? Post the code that is related to `response.data`

Comment: @GangadharJannu edited

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov edited code